# how do I add a image on top of another image?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I am editing images with video editor and I have just gotten a image cropped and sized when it crashes. I thought it was my ram so I lowered it down to 4500. my actual ram is 7.9GB. I add a image then I put a color behind it (while the image in from has image offset on and overdrop) then I expand the color and it crashes. every time no matter what image. I will be happy to explain further if you might have a clue but I have not included the information. I am using this for a school project so I really need to get bender to work. is there anything I can do?

summery:

I am putting a over-dropped, cropped, image offset image on top of another non-over-dropped, cropped, image offset background image and it keeps crashing.

[image]

Comment: could you submit a blend file to better understand the issue?

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: You can add your .blend file here http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: The images weren't packed in the blend so I couldn't replicate your problem, but one possible solution is to close out all the VSE windows you have open. For some reason you have like 10 VSE windows open and that might be contributing to the problem.